# PHP - How to add stuff from a database into a newsletter?

Tags: php, newsletter

Hey guys. I need help for a project for school. Essentially, I need to write a program that sends newsletters. I can send the newsletters and stuff, but the main issue I'm having is that the newsletter needs to contain things that are contained in a database. How exactly do I draw those things and put them into a newsletter? The bulk of it needs to be in PHP, but Java and stuff can be used, if needed. Also, I cant install anything on my portion of the schools server, so I cant use any CMS's and stuff.

Comment: What kind of database is it? sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are writing this for fun and learning, don't do it.

You will get your IP blacklisted and  have lots of problems. there are regulations (CAN SPAM etc) and best practices (SPF, domain keys etc) you need to follow if you want this to be successful. Otherwise you will not get any of your mail delivered, and possibly a call form your ISP.

How do you handle unsubscribes? How are you going to handle bounces? Mail loops? Blacklisting of problem addresses? This is not a simple topic.

You would be better off purchasing a email management system;.

[Lyris](http://www.lyris.com/solutions/listmanager/) makes one that you can install. There are other free/open source projects as well (majordomo, mailman etc).

Heed these words intrepid e-mailer!

Comment: This is for a school project, so I guess it falls under learning.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, do you have basic problems with querying your content from your database?

Comment: What's your problem than? You can just query your content and format it and send it as an html email or make an pdf out of it and send that one.. I don't see what you are having difficulties with :)

Comment: Haha...well how exactly do I  do that? I'm still pretty new to using MySql and PHP. Are there any good tutorials you could recommend to get the newsletters thing down??

Comment: For sending a mail with html of to create a pdf and send it by mail?

Comment: well...to tale stuff from a database, a list of events with a a title, and description, etc., into an html page or pdf(whichever is easier I guess, that portion doesnt matter as much), and send it by email. So pretty much take stuff from a database, and send it via email.